# Finding the Local Truncation Error for the Explicit Euler Scheme

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, truncation-error

I need to demonstrate finding the LTE for the Explicit Euler scheme when  i) $\mu=\frac{1}{6}$ and ii) $\mu\neq\frac{1}{6}$.
I have been looking for a reference text/video and I looked at the lecturers notes but I really was struggling to follow how to even begin. I know I will have to carry out a Taylor expansion but not much beyond that.

The scheme: $\mathrm{U}_{i}^{n+1}=\mathrm{U}_{i}^{n}+\mu(\mathrm{U}_{i+1}^{n}-2\mathrm{U}_{i}^{n}+\mathrm{U}_{i-1}^{n})$

where:
$1\le u\le M-1, n\ge 0$
$\mu=\frac{\bigtriangleup t}{(\bigtriangleup x)^2}$,
$\mathrm{U}_{i}^{n}: 0\lt i \lt M $,
$\mathrm{U}_{0}^{n}: n\ge 0$,
$\mathrm{U}_{M}^{n}: n\ge 0$

We apply this to the  heat equation using standard difference operators for the second derivative in space.

Comment: You should somewhere also add that you apply this to the PDE of the heat equation using standard difference operators for the second derivative in space.

Comment: Thanks Lutz, have added.

Answer (score 0):

You get two error sources that might partially compensate,
$$
u(x,t+Δt)-u(x,t)=Δt\,u_t+\frac12Δt^2\,u_{tt}+...
$$
and
$$
u(x+Δx,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-Δx,t)=Δx^2\,u_{xx}+\frac1{12}Δx^4\,u_{xxxx}+...
$$
Now use that also $u_{tt}=u_{xxxx}$

Comment: I follow the first line but I am not sure how we end up with $u_{xx}$ on the second line on the right hand side? Would you mind pointing me somewhere (sorry if this is quite basic, I am getting familiar with the material)

Comment: The left side is the second order difference quotient. As this is even symmetric, the right side will only contain even powers of $Δx$. The constant terms cancel, so what remains is what I wrote.